# Why fatal error while running app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multithreading, android-intent

I' am trying to make an app in which when a button is pressed in this case the button is b1, a toast is called which takes number from input and toasts the string text from textfield.I have got some errors Below logcat.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.x.losey;    
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.NetworkInterface;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        final Button b = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.Button2));
        final Button b1 = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.button));
        final EditText txt = (EditText)  (findViewById(R.id.editText));
        final EditText num = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.editText2));
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                boolean a1 ;
                Intent first = new Intent(MainActivity.this,second.class);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OK" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(first);
            }

        });
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                int i;
                int n;
                n = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(num));

                while(n!=0) {
                   String ab = txt.getText().toString();
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ab, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   n--;
                }
               }
            });
            return true;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <!--<TextView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/txtview1"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"-->
        <!--android:layout_gravity="top"-->
        <!--android:text="@string/LoseY"-->
        <!--android:textSize="25sp"-->
        <!--android:textStyle="bold" />-->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/desbtn"
        android:onClick=""
        android:text="@string/btn1"
        android:textColor="#FFFF"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:typeface="monospace" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"

            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:hint="@string/enter" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:height="50dp" android:textSize="28sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/desbtn"
        android:fontFamily="@string/btn1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:height="79dp"
        android:text="@string/showMe"
        android:textColor="#ffff9b80"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/input"
            android:id="@+id/editText2" android:layout_below="@+id/editText" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText" android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When the button = b1 is clicked i get the toast but only for 4 or 2 times when i remove the n then instead i add a value then i get a proper output.

And What's this Logcat error?

```
07-04 21:53:56.709  17773-17773/com.x.losey W/ResourceType﹕ No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x0000005d
07-04 21:53:56.710  17773-17773/com.x.losey D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-04 21:53:56.710  17773-17773/com.x.losey W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4165ed40)
07-04 21:53:56.712  17773-17773/com.x.losey E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.x.losey, PID: 17773
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5d
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:268)
        at com.x.losey.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:65)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18462)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-04 21:53:58.084  17773-17773/com.x.losey I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 17773 SIG: 9
07-04 21:53:59.709  18458-18458/com.x.losey I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:385>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.01
Build Date: 12/11/13 Wed
Local Branch: 8226workspace
Remote Branch:
Local Patches:
Reconstruct Branch:
07-04 21:53:59.735  18458-18458/com.x.losey D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
07-04 21:53:59.844  18458-18458/com.x.losey E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-04 21:53:59.844  18458-18458/com.x.losey E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-04 22:00:06.784  18458-18458/com.x.losey W/ResourceType﹕ No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x0000005d
07-04 22:00:06.784  18458-18458/com.x.losey D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-04 22:00:06.784  18458-18458/com.x.losey W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4165ed40)
07-04 22:00:06.788  18458-18458/com.x.losey E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.x.losey, PID: 18458
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5d
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:268)
        at com.x.losey.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:65)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18462)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invo`enter code here`ke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-04 22:00:08.438  18458-18458/com.x.losey I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 18458 SIG: 9
```

Comment: The logcat is saying that you passed an integer to Toast.maketest.. .but the given code is passing a String, are you sure this is the activity generating the error?

Comment: Yeah..Can you tell me how to store the value entered in inputText by the user?

Comment: what do you mean by store?

Comment: How to store the value entered by the user in an integer variable?

Comment: Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString())

Comment: @Pozzo Apps SUPERB NOW I AM GETTING THIS ERROR...Process: com.x.losey, PID: 21746
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "android.widget.EditText{41f50c60 VFED..CL .F...... 32,224-688,303 #7f080003 app:id/editText2}"
            at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
            at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
            at com.x.losey.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:58)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)

Comment: It's this line "n = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(num));", you are trying to convert a EditText to Integer.

Answer (score -1):

Change to MainActivity to:

```
private Button b;
private Button b1;
private EditText txt;
private EditText num;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button2);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    txt = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.editText);
    num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean a1 ;
            Intent first = new Intent(MainActivity.this,second.class);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OK" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            startActivity(first);

        }


    });
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            int i;
            int n;
            n = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(num));

            while(n!=0)
            {
               String ab = txt.getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ab, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                n--;
            }


           }

        });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}

}
```